# Using TPM under embedded Linux on ARM

Tags: arm, embedded-linux, arm64, tpm

I want to learn about using TPM in embedded Linux on ARM for secureboot, TrustZone etc. But I'm currently lost finding a good starting point.

I used the search engines and read some stuff like "DEN0006D_Trusted_Board_Boot_Requirements" and "Infineon-ISPN-Use-Case-Secured-boot-for-ARM-processor-platforms-ABR-v01_00-EN". But nothing which really helped me gaining knowledge.

Either I used the wrong searching words or the information is mainly closed. The most stuff I found is about TPM and Windows...

Can someone recommend any webpage, book, video or something else to start?

Edit: Beside the things in the solution, I can recommend the free open book "A Practical Guide to TPM 2.0" https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4302-6584-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using TPM lately on an embedded Linux and it's really a hard topic. 
If you are talking about TPM itself, the first thing is which version you are using.
I am assuming that you are using TPM 2.0.

- A good starting point for me was: [tpm-js](https://google.github.io/tpm-js/). You can use this tool
  to learn a few things about TPM. You can browse sources of this project to
  get a little deeper knowledge.
- Then you can use [Tpm2-tss](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tss) library. Only a few months ago they
  implemented the FAPI layer that simplifies the whole development.
- And also there is a TPM 2.0 architecture [doc](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TPM-Rev-2.0-Part-1-Architecture-01.07-2014-03-13.pdf) that can help you a
  lot, but I don't think it is a good starting point.
- The last and very good source of information for me ware the people behind tpm2-tss library. Ask them on the tpm2-tss Git-Hub page.

I don't recommend you to use tpm2 tools. There ware a lot of changes lately and it will be really confusing for you in the beginning. First you need to learn the differences between hierarchies and the difference between primary key and it's child keys. A lot of these information you will find in tpm-js.

Comment: Thank you! I will read those recommendations. Yes I am using a TPM 2.0